# how to calculate np.nanmean of 2d array

Tags: arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a dictionary containing 2d arrays. I tried to calculate the mean by this way but it does not work because, an arrays contains nan values also. So is there any simpler ways  to calculate the mean?

```
All = np.zeros(385000).reshape(550,700)

for i  in dic.keys():
    a = dic[i]['data']
    avg = (All+a)/len(dic.keys())
```

Comment: So, you tried `np.nanmean` and that didn't work? How did you use it?

Comment: suppose I have a = np.array([2,np.nan,5,4]).reshape(2,2) and b = np.array([np.nan,3,7,2]).reshape(2,2), I tried to calculate np.nanmean(a,b) but it does not work...I am expecting result like array([[2, 3], [6, 3]]) for above example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to finding the mean considering elementwise across both inputs `a` and `b`, ignoring the `NaNs`. So, one way would be to stack those two arrays with [`np.dstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html), which would stack `a` and `b` along the third axis and then simply use [`np.nanmean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) along the same axis. Thus, we would have a *simple* implementation like so -

```
np.nanmean(np.dstack((a,b)),axis=2)
```

Sample run -

```
In [28]: a
Out[28]: 
array([[  2.,  nan],
       [  5.,   4.]])

In [29]: b
Out[29]: 
array([[ nan,   3.],
       [  7.,   2.]])

In [30]: np.nanmean(np.dstack((a,b)),axis=2)
Out[30]: 
array([[ 2.,  3.],
       [ 6.,  3.]])
```

For a case when you would be getting those `2D` arrays from a dictionary as shown in the posted code of the question, you can use a loop-comprehension to gather those arrays as a `3D` array with `np.dstack` and finally use `np.nanmean` along the last axis, like so -

```
np.nanmean(np.dstack([d['data'] for d in dic]),axis=2)
```

Comment: this is what I was expecting .. :) but could you please help me to implement this in above problem...

Comment: @bikuser For that I need to know what's `a` and `b` in your above problem.

Comment: as you can see in the  for loop 'a' is the 2d array. So I have numbers of 2d arrays from which i want to calculate mean...I hope you understand

Comment: @bikuser See if the edited section codes work for you?

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is absolutely good but `np.dstack((a,b))` might seem not very strighforward or intuitive. We can also use `np.stack()` which gives more intuitive display. See samples below.

#### Code

```
a=np.array([[2,np.nan],[5,4]])
b=np.array([[np.nan,3],[7,2]])
c=np.stack((a,b),axis=0)
print(a)
print('='*50)
print(b)
print('='*50)
print(c)
print('='*50)
print(np.nanmean(c,axis=0))
```

#### Output

```
[[ 2. nan]
 [ 5.  4.]]
==================================================
[[nan  3.]
 [ 7.  2.]]
==================================================
[[[ 2. nan]
  [ 5.  4.]]

 [[nan  3.]
  [ 7.  2.]]]
==================================================
[[2. 3.]
 [6. 3.]]
```

Difference between `np.dstack()` and `np.stack()` can be found with the following example I wrote.

#### Code

```
dr1=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
print(dr1)
dr2=np.array([[9,8,7],[6,5,4],[3,2,1]])
print(dr2)
print('='*50)
dr3=np.dstack((dr1,dr2))
print(dr3.shape)
print(dr3)
print(np.sum(dr3,axis=2)) # This will be (row,col,time) but display (col,time) => (row,col) in each row, the 1 in dr2 will be in [3,3,2] => 3 [3,2]
print('='*50)
dr4=np.stack((dr1,dr2),axis=0) # This will be (time,row,col) and display (row,col) => (row,col) in each time, the 1 in dr2 will be in [2,3,3] => 2 [3,3]
print(dr4.shape)
print(dr4)
print(np.sum(dr4,axis=0))
```

#### Output

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
[[9 8 7]
 [6 5 4]
 [3 2 1]]
==================================================
(3, 3, 2)
[[[1 9]
  [2 8]
  [3 7]]

 [[4 6]
  [5 5]
  [6 4]]

 [[7 3]
  [8 2]
  [9 1]]]
[[10 10 10]
 [10 10 10]
 [10 10 10]]
==================================================
(2, 3, 3)
[[[1 2 3]
  [4 5 6]
  [7 8 9]]

 [[9 8 7]
  [6 5 4]
  [3 2 1]]]
[[10 10 10]
 [10 10 10]
 [10 10 10]]
```